# MY XCode datatips are not showing up

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, macos

I've got a little problem and I'm hoping someone here can help me out. I've used XCode pretty regularly for a while now and have made plenty of use of the Debugger datatips. All of the sudden today on a new project that I am working on, they are not there. The setting is toggled on under the Run->Debugger Display->Datatips menu, but they just aren't showing up for this project. If I go into any of my other projects or make another new project they show up fine.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have two solutions for when I get random weirdness with a specific Xcode project:

- quit Xcode, trash the "build" folder for the project, open up the project again and re-build (harmless, just costs you a rebuild)
- quit Xcode, delete foo.xcodeproj/username.mode1v3 and foo.xcodeproj/username.pbxuser (relatively harmless - you lose personal settings such as debugger breakpoints and custom executable settings - the files get re-created with default settings)

I know it's just voodoo but these seem to fix a lot of random problems.

Comment: You don't need to quit Xcode and manually trash the build folder, doing a "Clean All" will remove all the build files for you.

Comment: @Rob - Actually "Clean All" doesn't seem to be quite as thorough as this - I've seen situations where some rogue folders and files were left after a Clean All - deleting these manually then fixed the build problem (usually it's a mysterious inability to find headers that were previously found OK).